# Can I return a Task directly with HttpResponseMessage, such no async declaration is needed

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have the following WebAPI action and is wondering if returning `Task<bool>` and return `_store.ContainerExistsAsync(container)` directly is better;

I ask because, if I understand async/await correctly, the compiler creates a statemachine at the await to return to the same state. Returning the task directly without having to await it in the action, would that be theoretical faster?

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContainer(string container)
    {
        if (container.Length < 3 ||
            container.Length > 63 ||
            !Regex.IsMatch(container, @"^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$"))
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { errors = new string[1] { "Container Name is not alowed." } })            

        return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, await _store.ContainerExistsAsync(container));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you *can* implement an asynchronous method without `async` and `await`, then go ahead; `async`/`await` will add overhead.

This is commonly seen when the last line of a method has the only `await` and looks like `return await ...;`

In your particular example, I'm not 100% sure whether this would work since the method is doing something after the `await`.

It's easy enough to make it return the `Task<bool>` from `ContainerExistsAsync` directly, but the error handling would also need to change. If throwing a `HttpResponseException` works well enough, then yes, you would be able to implement an asynchronous method without using `async`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Maybe I need to redesign my error handling. Can i get the exact same behavior as above by throwing a exception ?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm not 100% sure about.